# From a list and given target value, how to calculate percentile

Tags: python, list, percentile

[1, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 7] : This is my input list. How do I calculate what percentile is the element 4? (Or any other element)

Comment: This is for a huge data set and a target value that is given. Something similar to the percentile value they calculate for competitive exams.

Comment: post the code that you have written for the task.

Comment: I suggest you turn off your computer. Get a statistics book that explains how to calculate this by hand. After you can solve some problems by hand, write down the steps that is required to calculate the percentile. Computer programming is problem solving first and writing code second.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the list is sorted, the percentile of a given value is:

```
(nums.index(value) + 1) / len(nums)
```